# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

Emacs's [first moderator election](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Dan] [image: Gilles] [image: Jordon Biondo]

They'll be replacing [the existing crew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [Jonathan Leech-Pepin](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/337/jonathan-leech-pepin) and [Malabarba](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/50/malabarba) who did so much to make Emacs—Stack Exchange such a pleasant place to visit.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6235821619281920/0).

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to Jonathan Leech-Pepin and Malabarba.

Thanks also to Constantine, PythonNut and elethan for participating in the election. It's good to have people who volunteer to be guides-cum-janitors.

I'm sure you'll keep up all the rest of the work that doesn't require additional privileges, so thank you all.

Comment: Congrats to you and the other moderators.